How to migrate Data Cloud Ingestion API Connector from one org to another?
How to migrate Data Cloud Ingestion API Connector from one org to another?
Per Salesforce documentation:
https://partnersolutions.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#1N000002LpRp/a/8V000002tOBI/O9xuIQS3Lg4qE2GWiQHbQLgcTurb0iGpKXoGuQ22e.A
direct metadata deployment should be possible without Data Kit.
Also, metadata API coverage report page:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/62
Shows DataConnectorIngestApi as deployable without Data Kit by matadata API or sfdx.

Still, we struggle to deploy or retrieve Data Cloud Ingestion API Connector.
We are not able to retrieve or deploy Data Cloud Ingestion API Connector either by Data Kit package installtion or by direct SFDX or metadata API deployment.
Even when we retrieve metadata DataConnectorIngestApi, it contains only label
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataConnectorIngestApi xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <masterLabel>test</masterLabel>
    <sourceName>test</sourceName>
</DataConnectorIngestApi>

and it doesn't contain all the objects and fields defined by this connector.
Is documentation wrong and this is not really supported?

Per SF Support response for Case #469140829
December 4 at 3:24 PM CET

The engineering team has informed me that the ingestion API connector
for the Data Kit needs to be manually configured in the target
organization, as we are unable to deploy it directly from the source
org. This step is necessary to deploy the data streams in the target
org.
We have also requested the creation of an article to address this
issue, and once it becomes available, I will promptly share it with
you.

Which basically means Ingestion API connector is not actually supported and one has to manually import yaml file to every new Data Cloud org where this has to be imported.

Update from the 2nd of January 2025.

SF Support provided the link for the help article

Looks like it is possible to deploy Ingestion API connector via DataKit Connect API, however, the documentation is vague and it is hard to guess the correct attributes.


By method of trial and errors finally I have found how this can be deployed.
POST https://{{domain}}/services/data/v{{version}}/actions/custom/flow/sfdatakit__DeployDataKitComponents
{
    "inputs": [
        {
            "dataKitComponentsInput": [
                {
                    "componentType": "DataStreamBundle",
                    "bundleConfig": {
                        "connectorType": "INGESTAPI",
                        "bundleName": "DataKit", # <-- I failed first since tried to put here Data Stream name, instead this must be DataSourceBundleDefinition name, which coincides with Data Kit name, this should not be the Data Stream name
                        "forceNoRefresh": true,
                        "bundleIngestApiConfig": {
                            "connectorName": "IngestionAPIConnector"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "dataKitNameInput": "DataKit",
            "dataKitDataSpaceInput" : "default"
        }
    ]
}

